# Triggering Zap A by passing a POST function from Zap B

Tags: python, webhooks, zapier

Using Zapier, I'm trying to set up a Zap that will run once a day and go through a spreadsheet to pick up anything with a specific keyword and add it to another sheet, remove it from the original sheet, and rinse and repeat. I'm using Daily Schedule trigger to run some Python code with a Post function to send the webhook. The URL links to another Zap with a Catch Hook trigger, which should execute when that webhook comes in to run through the steps to adjust the spreadsheets, and then concludes with an A/B path which will repeat the webhook if there are still more instances of the keyword to move/delete. However, my Zap is not triggering to the webhook, and I'm not sure why. I'm very new to webhooks and been unable to find an answer on my own.

```
import requests

hookUrl = 'https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/123456/1abcd2/'
id = input.get('value')

response = requests.post(hookUrl, id)

id = int(id)+1

return {'value': id}
```

I would expect the code to execute a post to the webhook URL and trigger the Zap, but the Zap does not react. The code executes successfully otherwise with returning the incremented ID.

Any insight?

Comment: Shot in the dark, but I would guess that your post request needs to send JSON, not just the id itself. To see exactly the format that the request is sending, try pointing it at a https://requestbin.com/ instead of the other hook url.

Comment: That was absolutely the problem! Thank you for helping an ickle newbie automate their work, you've saved me a decent chunk of time :)

Comment: no problem! you should post your solution as an answer to help others who may have the same question!

Comment: Done. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked:

```
import requests

hookUrl = 'https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/123456/1abcd2/'
payload = {'id': input.get('value')}
r = requests.post(hookUrl, data=payload)

id = int(input.get('value'))+1

return {'value': id}
```

The error was in not defining a key for the variable now called `payload`. Once the key was added to keep the JSON formatting (thank you, xavdid!), it worked like a charm. Now, I have a Zap that sends out this webhook every day at midnight, which runs a DIFFERENT Zap with a final pathing step which either a.) terminates the Zap or b.) sends a webhook and loops the Zap again, depending on whether any entries in a Spreadsheet with a given variable still exist.

Thanks for the help!